# How use cd command to access a directory with space

Tags: 14.04, bash, scripts

How do I use "cd" to access a directory with a space, for example "XML 5.1 Final Fields" in a bash script

I tried `cd XML 5.1 Final Fields`

But it's giving the `No such file or directory` error.

This is the script:

```
#! /bin/bash
xmlfolder="XML/ \/5.1/ \/Final/ \/Fields"
xmlpath="/home/george/Desktop/m5u/test/$xmlfolder"
cd $xmlpath
```

```
ls /home/george/Desktop/m5u/test/    
XML 5.1 Final Fields
```

```
~/Desktop/m5u/test$ ll
drwxr-xr-x  9 george george      4096 Feb 18 12:44 XML 5.1 Final Fields
```

this is the error I get when I run the script

```
line 5: cd: /home/george/Desktop/m5u/test/XML\: No such file or directory
```

Comment: You could type `cd george` and then hit tab it autocompletes the command if it finds suitable candidates. Then hit enter to fire up the command.

Comment: Also `stat george`+TAB+ENTER to see how the file is actually named. It might have some space or other stuff at the end.

Comment: See also http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes

Comment: It's "\ " (backslash-space), not " \" (space-backslash). But really... read the link above.

Comment: What is the actual path? `george ulahnnan linux` or `XML[...]`?

Comment: You know, this question has been asked and answered multiple times here. http://askubuntu.com/search?q=file+name+with+spaces

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your variable `xmlfolder` is wrong. It should be

```
xmlfolder=XML\ 5.1\ Final\ Fields
```

or
="XML 5.1 Final Fields"

You don't need the `/` in the path - as it's just one folder. You also don't need the `""` if you are also using `\`. Pick one.

---

since your edit with the `ls` command, I can see there may be a space at the end of your folder name. I'd suggest you remove the space, either by renaming in nautilus or with the `mv` command.

If you want to keep the space, your variable name should be this:

```
xmlfolder=XML\ 5.1\ Final\ Fields\
```

or

```
xmlfolder="XML 5.1 Final Fields "
```

Note that if you use the First option with the `\` character, you also need to refer to the variable with `""`, i.e. `"$xmlfolder"`.

---

The error suggests that `cd` is unhappy with the path.

Try changing the `cd` command from this

```
cd $xmlpath
```

to

```
cd "$xmlpath"
```

To be perfectly honest, you shouldn't need to `cd` in a bash script. Just refer to everything with an absolute path.

---

In summary, your `xmlfolder=` line should be `xmlfolder=XML\ 5.1\ Final\ Fields`, and your `cd` line should be `cd "xmlpath"`.

My pronouns are He / Him

Comment: xmlfolder="XML\ 5.1\ Final\ Fields"
xmlpath=/home/george/Desktop/m5u/test/$xmlfolder
cd $xmlpath

getting same error

Comment: @GeorgeUlahannan You've got to be clear about your actual path, otherwise no one's gonna be able to help you. You should start by [editing](http://askubuntu.com/posts/736214/edit) your question so that it shows the output of `stat *` in the directory you're running the script in.

Comment: You know, this question has been asked and answered multiple times here. http://askubuntu.com/search?q=file+name+with+spaces